# convert raw sequence to fasta using awk

Tags: awk, fasta

I have a list of short nucleotide sequences, one per line, which I need to convert to fasta format. I'm trying with awk, but my code so far just hangs, using a 10 line test file. My input file looks like:

```
ACGTACGTACGT
CGTACGTACGTA
GTACGTACGTAC
TACGTACGTACG
```

My output should have a numbered header line for each sequence - the number could be just counting from 1 or taking the line number from the input file (which should be the same), with the sequence on a new line, like this:

```
> seq 1
ACGTACGTACGT
> seq 2
CGTACGTACGTA
> seq 3
GTACGTACGTAC
> seq 4
TACGTACGTACG
```

I tried using the NR variable for the count:

```
awk -F '{echo "> seq ",NR;"\n"; print $0}' in.txt > out.fasta
```

Any suggestions welcome - I'm new at this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{print "> seq " ++count ORS $0}'  Input_file
```

In case you want to use `FNR` line count variable for `awk` then you could try following too.

```
awk '{print "> seq " FNR ORS $0}'  Input_file
```

You could re-direct output of above commands to an output_file by appending `> output_file` to above commands too.

Comment: Brilliant, these both work, thanks. So newline is the default record separator, handy!

Comment: @Joanne, `ORS` is the one `awk` provides whose value will be new line so since we are printing here newt text ahead of current line so I used `ORS` to print a new line and yes default record separator will be new line only for `awk`.